# Any way to display category in SharePoint online news article web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-news

Need to display the category in the news article in the red box of the OOTB features in SharePoint Online.

For example I have the category for the news:

- Sports news
- Technology news

Can I display it in the news article in the image below with the red box?

Is there any way to do this in OOTB?

Or else in custom way, can anyone recommends me a good article for SPFx.

[image]

Thank you so much appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using news web part or highlighted content web part?

Comment: I used news web part

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot customize SharePoint out of the box news web part to add more column values in the news web part.

However, you can develop a custom news web part as per your requirements using SharePoint framework(SPFx).

**Documentation**: [sharepoint-framework-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

---

You can build custom web parts like below to SharePoint news:

[image]

**Source**: [SharePoint News Posts with SPFx](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-news)

You can find other news web parts and source code at:

1. [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts//tree/main/samples/)
2. [Global News](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-global-news)